# How do I implement smooth movement in a Box2D platform game?

Tags: java, box2d, platformer, slick

I have implemented a character in JBox2D which moves with the help of a wheel rotating at the bottom of it. The movement is the best result I've had 'till now but it's a little glitchy when the character stands on the edge. So I am thinking should I use five smaller wheels instead of a big wheel. The wheel/wheels will not be visible in the finished product, now they are drawn for debugging. [Here is a video](http://youtu.be/Ux3kaxo7FJQ). Is there a better way to do this using JBox2D?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Can you explain exactly what the issue is with your current implementation?

Comment: Well i want my character to stay on the edge even if only one 1/5 of him is on the platform and the rest 4/5 are suspended in air.

Comment: Well that's what you get for using a wheel. Unless the terrain demands it I suggest just using a box. Not to mention a box feels more nimble and maneuverable.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure what the reason for the wheel is. If you're not even going render it. Unless you're trying to cheat the physics system? You can't really complain about a wheel not acting like a square :/

Comment: If i use only a square i can't move the character unless i mess with his position and/or velocity. In my game there will be explosions and bullets. If i mess  with position, when an explosion will pop up it will not act right. I hope you understand my need of using this.

Comment: No I dont. As long as the friction is not infinite and the box's inertia is infinite you can move the box with forces and not worry about it rotating.

Comment: The reason for a wheel is to overcome jagged ledges. A simple box object will get stuck every time one of your platforms is even the tiniest bit higher than the last one. However, indeed, this solution also means that the character will not be standing on the platform when being 4/5 in the air.

Answer (score 1):

When using a physics system, you need to use the physics system. The way to move things around is to apply forces to them.

You mention that you'll have explosions and bullets and you want them to react correctly, that's fine. You can apply a movement force and explosions and bullets will apply their own forces too.

This will actually give you better results because your physics system needs to know all the forces and velocities of the objects to properly calculate their response. If you were to leave the physics system entirely out of the movement of your characters, when one of your characters experienced the force of an explosion, it would react as if it was standing still. Even though it may be moving towards or away from the explosion. For example: if your character is running towards an explosion, they will not be thrown back as far because of their forward momentum.

Basically, if you're using a physics system, you need to keep it up-to-date with what the objects in your world are doing.

Comment: In Box2D, this is accomplished with Body.applyForce() or Body.applyLinearImpulse(). Here's a helpful tutorial (I suggest reading the whole series): http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/forces